# Get intellisense data for uncompiled projects

Tags: linux, visual-studio, compilation, intellisense

I inherited a project setup from a previous programmer. He used to develop for linux, but instead of coding directly in ubuntu, he shared the drives with samba and used Visual Studio to edit the files.

Now I can't compile this project in Visual Studio directly obviously, so I can't get data for intellisense and such. Would it be possible to associate symbols without compiling?

I know that what I ask seems counter intuitive, but Vim plugin OmniCPP does not come with a compiler and yet, is able to provide code completition up to a certain degree.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial addin [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/downloads/default.asp) can help.  How well it helps is dependent upon how much information it can get from the project (if one exists): things like source files, header files and include directories.  If no project is being used, you can create a dummy project just as a container to associate source and header files (not for compiling).